# Android full screen, EditText pushes other view up

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an app and have a problem.

I have an vieww like the image below with an image and an edittext field the right position. But when i click on the edittext field and it gets the focus it pushes the other view up.

I have the full screen flag and if i dont use that it works perfect and the image keeps theire position and dont pushed up. I need that with full screen flag.

Is there someone who have some example or can help me. I have used the 'windowSoftInputMode' with all the posibles values.

Here my layout code and examples how it now works and how it needs to be.

xml layout source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical|none" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <!-- layout for images -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/image"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- layout for edit text -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="bottom" 
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageview"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tekstbox"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the image how i start in the activity

[image: This is my start position in the view (image on top and edittext below)]

When i click in the edittext field i want my view to react as below:

[image: wanted reaction]

But when the edittext gots focus it pushes everything up like below:

[image]

Does someone know how to solve this with the fullscreen flag on?

Thanks.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: No i still havent.

Answer (score 1):

User this line of code in your Manifest.xml. In the activity where the problem is occuring

```
 <activity

           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustNothing">  

  </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line in your manifest file in activity tag:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

and add `ScrollView` in your layout file like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
android:scrollbars="vertical|none" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- layout for images -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="top" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- layout for edit text -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageview"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tekstbox"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </RelativeLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks its a big step, but when i start my activity now my edittext is always overlaying on the image. It doesnt push up anymore but its on the wrong position.

Comment: Yes i have inserted it there. Alsu using: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Dont know if that mater?

Comment: android:layout_below="@+id/imageview" in Second Layout

Comment: I tried your answer and it places the edittext below the image as expected. but the screen ist using the full height. I need the second relativeLayout placed at the bottom of the screen. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: There is only way you have to create space there by using some view like TextView its visibility is invisible.

Comment: Ok so i need to add a TextView with an height? But then it pushes up again because i set an static height. Do you know an other way? Thanks for all your responses.

Comment: Calculate the height and width of the screen :                        try {
   // getting width and height of a screen in pixels
   Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
   metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
   display.getMetrics(metrics);
   widthScreen = metrics.widthPixels;
   heightScreen = metrics.heightPixels; 
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }                                                                    After calculating height of the screen minus image height and edittext height also remaining height is set to textView.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But then i am back where i started because the edittext is on the bottom of the view. But when i focus on the edit text it pushes everything up. I have searched before by calculating the screen size minus the keyboard but its not always right.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in your manifest file in activity tag:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```